# What is the correct way to import modules in python library?

Tags: python

When you write a python library, and want to import one module in it from another, what is the correct way to do it, so that imports work both when the library is imported from outside and when some unit tests are run from the library directory?

If you do

```
import some_module
from some_module import something
```

it works when run from the library directoy, but when imported from outside, produces `ImportError: No module named 'some_module'`.

You can do

```
from . import some_module
import my_library.some_other_module
from .some_module import something
```

but it will not work if you import the library from the unittest placed in the same directory.

Finally, you can play with `sys.path` and/or move unit tests to some other directory.

What's the best solution?

**Edit:** Just to make it clear, I'd like to run the unittests using `python -m unittest` in the top directory of the library. So far I made it work by adding

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

to the beginning of the unit test files. As an alternative it's possible to write a short shell script that will add the parent directory to `PYTHONPATH` and then run unittests. I wonder if there are better ways to deal with it?

Comment: Play with `PYTHONPATH` instead of `sys.path` maybe...

Comment: I found your question difficult to understand and confusing. Can you clarify what you actually did? My guess is that you did the unittest *inside* the library when you actually needed to do it *outside* of the library. i.e., `$ ls .` should show your library directory.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs on [Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - the installation-dependent default.

If you write a library, the test code should usually interface with the library in the same manner that a user of the library would. This might mean adding the module to the the search path either by setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable, or by installing the module in the default 3rd party module location.

I would suggest running your tests from the base directory which holds your modules using the automated test discovery option

```
python -m unittest discover (python >= 2.7)
```

This will recursively find files matching `test_*.py` (i.e. within module dirs), but should set the python path relative to the parent dir.

Comment: Running unittests from the parent directory doesn't sound like a good solution since it will scan all the unrelated subdirectories in the parent directory.

Comment: Python searches those same directories when you import a module, so if you have excess files in your python search path maybe a restructure is in order. In practice, the searching is almost instant for most projects. You can also run specific modules from the parent directory with, for example `python -m foo.tests.test_bar`